# Как задать отступ между разными секциями?

Tags: html, css

Как задать отступ между секциями?
[image: Пример расположения блоков]

Вот есть две секции:

```html
<div class="kaufman__triangle"></div>
  </section>
  </main>
  <footer class="footer">
```

Между последней секцией и footer'ом был задан отступ в 100рх.
Что и в какую CSS писать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
footer{
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Отступ появился , но вместо черного цвета стал белый. как исправлять?

Comment: @ВалерийГлушков а про цвета в вашем вопросе ни слова. Значит уточните вопрос, покажите нормальный пример с нормальными цветами и конкретнее опишите желаемое поведение ([править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1127635/edit))

Comment: Извиняюсь , попробую сформулировать вопрос правильно. Мне нужен отступ между двумя секциями в 100 пикселей , но что бы цвет был как у footer или вышестоящей секции (я там напутал там не черный и серый а 2 серых быть должно было , но это я исправил)

Comment: Пробуйте с padding, код исправил. И желательно бы более информативный скриншот скинуть

Comment: В точку. Спасибо